# Keyboard hides automatically on some mobile phones

Tags: android, angular, cordova

We have an angular 6 app, that is wrapped in cordova android (version 7)
When the app is run on a mobile phone, we sometimes have issues that the keyboard popup's and directly hides again, or just doesn't show up.
When the issues occurs and you keep holding the input until a menu pops up, thereafter the keyboard is working as expected in the app.

This occurs on some devices (Samsung s7, but not on samsung S8 /S9 / A5)